# pytest mocker not resetting mock between tests causing incorrect results

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-importlib, pytest-mock

I am running into a problem with pytest mocker which I am not sure how to describe

Suppose I have this code

### `dummy_module.py`

```py
from dummy_module_2 import function_that_returns_list_of_dict

def delete_d_key():
    keyVal_list= function_that_returns_list_of_dict()
    for x in keyVal_list:
        del x['d']
```

### `dummy_module_2.py`

```py
def function_that_returns_list_of_dict():
    return [
        {
            'k' : [1,2],
            'd' : [3,4],
        },
        {
            'k' : [1,2],
            'd' : [3,4],
        },
        {
            'k' : [1,2],
            'd' : [3,4],
        }
    ]
```

And I write the following `pytest` tests for it:

### `test_pyt.py`

```
from copy import deepcopy

def test_A(mocker):
    dummy_output = [
        {
            'k' : [4,5],
            'd' : [7,8],
        },
        {
            'k' : [4,5],
            'd' : [7,8],
        },
        {
            'k' : [4,5],
            'd' : [7,8],
        }
    ]
    with mocker.patch('dummy_module_2.function_that_returns_list_of_dict', return_value=deepcopy(dummy_output)):
        from dummy_module import delete_d_key
        delete_d_key()

def test_B(mocker):
    dummy_output = [
        {
            'k' : [4,5],
            'd' : [7,8],
        },
        {
            'k' : [4,5],
            'd' : [7,8],
        },
        {
            'k' : [4,5],
            'd' : [7,8],
        }
    ]
    with mocker.patch('dummy_module_2.function_that_returns_list_of_dict', return_value=deepcopy(dummy_output)):
        from dummy_module import delete_d_key
        delete_d_key()
```

The issue here is that the first test runs, and during the first test, the return value of the first mock object is mutated. The second test seems to see this old mutated value and therefore fails. Each of the mock calls is called via context manager, so I expect that it should tear down the patching at the end of each test and then call it again. This is not the case.

Is this a documented issue? Does this have anything to do with imports?

Answer (score 0):

You're patching the wrong thing. Because `delete_d_key` runs in the `dummy_module` module, you need to import the `function_that_returns_list_of_dict` **in that module**:

```
with mocker.patch(
    "dummy_module.function_that_returns_list_of_dict",
    return_value=deepcopy(dummy_output),
):
    from dummy_module import delete_d_key

    delete_d_key()
```

This works correctly, but produces the following warning:

> PytestMockWarning: Mocks returned by pytest-mock do not need to be used as context managers. The mocker fixture automatically undoes mocking at the end of a test. This warning can be ignored if it was triggered by mocking a context manager. https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remarks.html#usage-as-context-manager

So you can rewrite things like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from dummy_module import delete_d_key

dummy_output = [
    {
        "k": [4, 5],
        "d": [7, 8],
    },
    {
        "k": [4, 5],
        "d": [7, 8],
    },
    {
        "k": [4, 5],
        "d": [7, 8],
    },
]


def test_A(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        "dummy_module.function_that_returns_list_of_dict",
        return_value=deepcopy(dummy_output),
    )
    delete_d_key()


def test_B(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        "dummy_module.function_that_returns_list_of_dict",
        return_value=deepcopy(dummy_output),
    )
    delete_d_key()
```

These tests pass as expected.